# Make a drop down list on xcode like websites

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to make a drop down list that looks similar to registration pages on websites that have the arrow pointing to the button.  I have included an image of a yahoo registration page where this occurs and I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction to finding how to do this.  Thanks! [image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing for iPhone or iPad. If iPad, use a UIPopoverController with a UITableViewController as its contentViewController. Popover controllers have a method, presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated: that allows you to have its arrow point at the view that you launched it from.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom UIView that uses a UITableView. Everytime you click on a drop down list button, you can set your custom view's UITableView datasource object to the list of values you want to display.

You'll need to declare your custom view in your view controller and shift the X,Y coordinate of that custom view to the appropriate position when the user taps on the button.

I tend to use NSMutableArray in my custom view, then when I need the row, I call my custom view's "selectedRow" property.